# How can I send a message from Google Chrome extension to desktop application?

Tags: winapi, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message, desktop-application

I have a Windows desktop application which must work in collaboration with my Chrome extension.

Can I send a message to my desktop app somehow from Google Chrome extension?

Which IPC objects can I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see three options:

1. You could use the internet. You can have a remote service that both the chrome extension and your desktop app talk to, to communicate.
2. You could have your desktop app have a simple server built into it so that the chrome extension can make local http requests to it to communicate with it.
3. <strike>Use the Google NPAPI plugin functionality to have full access to the computer.</strike> [Now deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/npapi)

Comment: nice idea about local http server!

Answer (score 9):

These days you would use Chrome's native messaging API to send the message from your extension to a native messaging host. The latter can be a "real" executable that then passes the message on to your desktop application.

Documentation: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host

Answer (score 3):

chrome extension has a `native massage api` to communicate to native process,

see here:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging

Comment: This is the link for extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging