# IPC between chrome web extension an localhost (QLocalServer)

Tags: qt, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, ipc

My desktop application needs to communicate with my chrome web extension.
As suggested in several posts on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056380/how-can-i-send-a-message-from-google-chrome-extension-to-desktop-application), I want to do this via a local server.
However, I am new to web development and have no server programming experience.

Now I do not know how to establish the connection between server (localhost) and client (web extension).
The `QLocalServer` I am trying to use as local server only needs a server name like `"MyLocalServer"`. If the client would also be made with Qt, that name would be sufficient to know. But the web extension implementation idea is to use javascript and a `XMLHttpRequest`. I am concerned about two things with the XMLHttpRequest:

- How to connect to the local server when I only know its name? I do not know the port and all I see on the internet is like

  ```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://localhost:8081/sample.xml',true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  ```

  where you need to know the port number.
- Due to the same-origin policy, I am not sure if I can do it this way at all.
  Does it make a difference, if I do not need access to a file (like in the url above `/sample.xml`? I only want to communicate via streams. There is no need to access saved files on the harddrive.

If it helps, here is my first idea of the local Qt server:

server.h:

```
class QLocalServer;
class Server : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Server(QObject *parent = 0);
private slots:
    void onNewConnection();
    void sendResponse();
private:
    QLocalServer* server_;
};
```

server.cpp:

```
Server::Server(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    server_(new QLocalServer)
{
    server_->listen("MyLocalServer");
    connect(server_,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(onNewConnection()));
}

void Server::onNewConnection()
{
    qDebug()<<"New connection.";
}

void Server::sendResponse()
{
    qDebug()<<"Sending response...";
}
```

EDIT:

I am not limited to use `QLocalServer`, if it works, I could also use `QTcpServer`. Then I'd have an IP address and port number to use with the XMLHttpRequest, but unfortunately I could not make it work, either.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407778/connecting-to-tcp-socket-from-browser-using-javascript) post from 2013 that is about a similar topic, and it is suggested to either use XMLHttpRequest (as I tried above) or to use websockets.