# Two way communication between Chrome extention and win32 c++ application

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I need advice about the best way to make an application (written in c++/mfc) communicate with an extension in chrome (I am also studying edge chromium)

As far as I understand, the native application that the extension can communicate with by using native host messaging is launched by chrome. As my win32 application is launched by the user and not by chrome, I need the native application to be a third component, launched by chrome.

What is the best way to let my win32 application communicate with my native app ? Making it a COM server is a good idea ?

I have searched on the other posts but they often talk about the native app talking to another app, not the other way.

Thank you

Comment: You can use any standard method of communication between processes, [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

Comment: You could have your desktop app have a simple server built into it so that the chrome extension can make local http requests to it to communicate with it. For more information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056380/how-can-i-send-a-message-from-google-chrome-extension-to-desktop-application). Besides, in chrome documentation, it says extensions and apps can exchange messages with native applications that are registered as a [native messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host).

Comment: Hi, did you solved it?